# Cannot add content to a Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-core, wpf-core-3.0

I'm trying to create a custom version of `UserControl` to implement some standard animations for views when loading.

But when I add a `ContentPresenter` I'm not able to add content to my control. Why though?

Here is the Template I use for my custom control.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EzNintendo.Desktop.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatedView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatedView}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

and the default code for a custom control

```
public class AnimatedView : Control
{
    static AnimatedView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AnimatedView), 
                                                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AnimatedView)));
    }
}
```

and

and that is how I try to use it.

```
<controls:AnimatedView x:Class="MyView"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MControls;assembly=MControls">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" />
    </Grid>
</controls:AnimatedView>
```

When I remove the `Grid` it works just fine.

Comment: Control class doesn't have content. trying to derive AnimatedView from ContentControl

Comment: Or derive it from `UserControl` and override the the `ControlTemplate` in the XAML, inserting the `ContentPresenter` where needed.

Comment: @ByoungSamMoon Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Maybe you can add some more details.

Comment: more detail? just modify Control to ContentControl. or @MarkFeldman solution is good too.